# Error When Trying To Animate Brush on Diffuse Material

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I am trying to change the color of a 3D object using a storyboard.

I am receiving the following error when I hover over the 3D object.

> Cannot automatically create animation clone for frozen property values on 'System.Windows.Media.Media3D.DiffuseMaterial' objects. Only FrameworkElement and FrameworkContentElement (or derived) types are supported.

How do I unfreeze that value?

Here is the XAML in it's entirety.

```
<Window x:Class="SampleError.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="PowderLeftStoryboard">
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Brush.Color" Storyboard.TargetName="TestColor">
                    <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="Aqua"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PowderLeftStoryboard}"></BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
        <Viewport3D Name="MainViewport3D">
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera FieldOfView="51.0742000956825" NearPlaneDistance="0.1" FarPlaneDistance="10000" Position="-239.40625,212.041875,347.2875" LookDirection="0.548523987999613,-0.515612548719637,-0.658228785599536" UpDirection="0.330087109961553,0.856821859900201,-0.396104531953864"/>
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <Model3DGroup>
                        <Model3DGroup x:Name="PowdeLeft1__Group">
                            <Model3DGroup x:Name="Surge1__Group">
                                <GeometryModel3D x:Name="Surge1">
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-14.7428983847443,-21.4490043747483,-70.6662837967009 -18.5131735568926,-21.6766464374666,-66.9028941532197 -19.8931860896634,-21.9876091191022,-61.7619982331085 -9.59261449452252,-21.3656818484822,-72.0437862586335 -4.44232583592909,-21.4490043747483,-70.6662837967009 -0.672052571129482,-21.6766464374666,-66.902886523825 -4.4423244054176,-22.5262138634562,-52.8577164842134 -0.672054836106018,-22.2985737080865,-56.621109942392 0.70796103452496,-21.9876091191022,-61.7619982331085 -9.59261354084819,-22.6095363897222,-51.4802178369781 -14.7428983847443,-22.5262138634562,-52.8577164842134 -18.5131716495439,-22.2985737080865,-56.621109942392 -9.59261163349953,-40.9623522912522,-62.9097491047035 -14.7428983847443,-22.5262138634562,-52.8577164842134 -18.5131716495439,-22.2985737080865,-56.621109942392 -9.59261354084819,-22.6095363897222,-51.4802178369781 -4.4423244054176,-22.5262138634562,-52.8577164842134 -0.672054836106018,-22.2985737080865,-56.621109942392 0.70796103452496,-21.9876091191022,-61.7619982331085 -0.672052571129482,-21.6766464374666,-66.902886523825 -4.44232583592909,-21.4490043747483,-70.6662837967009 -9.59261449452252,-21.3656818484822,-72.0437862586335 -14.7428983847443,-21.4490043747483,-70.6662837967009 -18.5131735568926,-21.6766464374666,-66.9028941532197 -19.8931860896634,-21.9876091191022,-61.7619982331085"
                                                        TriangleIndices="0 1 2 3 0 2 4 3 2 5 4 2 6 7 8 9 6 8 10 9 8 11 5 2 11 8 5 11 10 8 12 13 14 15 13 12 16 15 12 17 16 12 12 18 17 12 19 18 12 20 19 12 21 20 12 22 21 12 23 22 12 24 23 12 14 24"
                                                        TextureCoordinates="9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625 9999.900390625,9999.900390625"/>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <MaterialGroup>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="TestColor" Brush="Red" />
                                            <SpecularMaterial Color="White" Brush="#FFB9B9B9" SpecularPower="6186"/>
                                        </MaterialGroup>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                </GeometryModel3D>
                            </Model3DGroup>
                        </Model3DGroup>
                        <Model3DGroup>
                            <PointLight x:Name="TrackBall" Position="-914.088256835938,3411.42358398438,-0.000154378387378529" Color="#FFFFFFF2"/>
                            <SpotLight x:Name="TrackBal00" Direction="0.46809049472328,0.585684324062387,-0.661713806186103" OuterConeAngle="20.0535221099854" InnerConeAngle="20.0535221099854" Position="-1653.18591308594,-2068.49975585938,2337.01806640625" Color="Black"/>
                        </Model3DGroup>
                    </Model3DGroup>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Is there a better way to dynamically change the color of the cone? Is it even possible?